# Why would a Whirlpool dryer only blow hot air?

Tags: repair, dryer

*This question is for a Whirlpool Model WED5840SW0 dryer.*

My dryer stopped working altogether after running hot for an entire cycle. I replaced the thermal fuse and then tried to run a cycle. No matter how I adjusted the dryer it would only blow air. It blows hot air under each heat setting (including Air Only setting) and during Cool Down.

I suspect the temperature dial is broken.

Comment: I'd have to say it's your selector switch.

Comment: @Jack. I assume you mean the temperature selector switch. That's what I was thinking. But then would that make it run hot all the time - even during cool down?

Comment: The contacts for "heat" in the temperature selector switch could be stuck, welded, closed. You could check it with an OHM meter.

Comment: @Jack. Thanks. I will.

Comment: @JACK make an answer outta that!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good chance that "heat" contacts on your temperature selector switch are stuck, welded together, so they don't open when you're switching modes. You can check it's operation with an OHM meter. Unplug the dryer first and disconnect the wires the wires to the switch but take a picture before you do so you'll be able to hook it back up correctly and won't have to come back here and ask another question :-)